# retriving specific data from LinkedList

Tags: java

I want to find students whose gender is female by using streams

`Student` class

```
public class Student {
    private String first;
    private String last;
    private int ID;
    private Gender gender;

    int next=0;

    List<Course> courses=new LinkedList<>();
    List<Student> students=new LinkedList<>();

    public Student(String first, String last, int iD, Gender gender) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        ID = iD;
        //this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void enroll(Course c) {
        courses.add(c);
    }

    public void isFemale(){
        Student s;
        return s.gender=Gender.F;
    }
}
```

`enum` class for genders

```
public enum Gender {
    M,F;
    private Gender gender;
}
```

`main` class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> studentsOfClass=new LinkedList<>();

        studentsOfClass.add(new Student("john","smith",01,Gender.M));
        studentsOfClass.add(new Student("mick","tayson",05,Gender.M));
        studentsOfClass.add(new Student("sara","conor",04,Gender.F));
        studentsOfClass.add(new Student("Tana","smith",02,Gender.F));

        Course c1=new Course("fiologiya","anna",0234);
        Course c2=new Course("mathematics","maria",1134);
        Course c3=new Course("phisics","luisa",0534);

        studentsOfClass.stream().limit(3).forEach(s->s.enroll(c1));

        Collection<Student> femaleStudents= studentsOfClass.stream().filter(Student::isFemale).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your Gender enum have a Gender field??

Answer (score 3):

You are using the Stream methods correctly, but your isFamele method is wrong. It should return boolean and check the gender of the current Student.

It should be :

```
public boolean isFemale() 
{
    return gender==Gender.F;
}
```

You should also unremark this constructor line - `//this.gender = gender;` - and probably remove `private Gender gender;` from the Gender enum.

In addition, you can change the type of `femaleStudents` from `Collection` to `List<Student>`, which is more accurate.